Scalar triple product and its relation to Volume of a Parallelopiped.
Consider a parallelepiped with edges made of three vectors, $\vec{A}$, $\vec{B}$, $\vec{C}$.
Now, let the angle between $\vec{A}$ and $\vec{B}$ be $\theta$. And, that between $\vec{C}$ and $(\vec{A} ×\vec{B})$ be $\phi$.
So, for the volume of the parallelepiped (say, $V$),
$$V=(\text{area of one face}) × (\text{height corresponding to that face and its parallel face})$$
We know that the area of a face made by vectors $\vec{A}$ and $\vec{B}$ is $|(\vec{A}×\vec{B})|$ $i.e.$ the magnitude cross product of the two vectors.
Also, height corresponding to the face made by vectors $\vec{A}$ and $\vec{B}$ is given by $C\cos{\phi}$.
Then,
$$V=|(\vec{A}×\vec{B})|×C\cos{\phi} \implies V=AB \sin{\theta}×C \cos{\phi}= ABC \sin{\theta} \cos{\phi}\tag{1}$$
Now, if we consider the face made by the vectors $\vec{B} \text{ and } \vec{C}$ and calculate volume using this face as the base, we get:
(notice that the angle between $\vec{A}$ and $(\vec{B}×\vec{C})$ is again $\phi$)
$$V=|(\vec{B}×\vec{C})|×A \cos{\phi}\tag{2}$$
Question
Now, since the volume would be the same, does this imply (from $eq(1)$), that the angle between vector $\vec{B} \text{ and } \vec{C}$ is again $\theta$, same as that between $\vec{A} \text{ and } \vec{B}$.Why?
As the alignment of $\vec{C}$ can be in any direction.
The angle between $\vec{A}$ and $(\vec{B}×\vec{C})$
The angle between $\vec{A}$ and $(\vec{B}×\vec{C})$ is again $\phi$(i.e. the angle between vector $\vec{C} \text{ and } (\vec{A}×\vec{B})$).
This can be shown using the fact that the angle between two vectors lying in a plane is equal to the angle between the perpendiculars of those vectors (found by rotating both in the same direction) in that same plane.
Clearly, $(\vec{B}×\vec{C})$ is perpendicular to $\vec{C}$ and $\vec{A}$ is perpendicular to $(\vec{A}×\vec{B})$.
Now to prove that the angle between the respective vectors (as mentioned above) are equal, we have to show that all the four vectors are in the same (even parallel would do) plane.
One way is to show that the plane formed by vectors $(\vec{B}×\vec{C})$ and $\vec{A}$ (say, plane $1$) is parallel to that formed by vectors $(\vec{A}×\vec{B})$ and $\vec{C}$ (say,plane $2$).
Clearly, the normal vector to plane $1$ is parallel(even same) to that of plane $2$ as both are $(\vec{A}×\vec{B}×\vec{C})$.
This shows that the angle between the two pair of vectors mentioned are indeed same and leads to the ambiguity ($eq(2)$), which is my question.
I hope this made the question more clear.

A "side" of a polyhedron is called a face. The term "side" usually means an edge of a polygon.

@J.G. Sorry for the confusion

Have you tried actual numerical examples of the vectors involved? What did you discover?

@Somos Yeah, I got it now. Using numerical examples,one can clearly see that the products $\vec{A}×(\vec{B}×\vec{C})$ is not the same as $(\vec{A}×\vec{B})×\vec{C}$

In symbols, your assumption is:

$\angle\,\vec{A}\,(\vec{B}\times\vec{C})\,=\,\angle(\vec{A}\times\vec{B})\,\vec{C}$

This is false. The error in your justification is (paraphrased):

The normal vector to $[$the plane generated by $\vec{A}$ and $\vec{B}\times\vec{C}]$
is the same as the normal vector to $[$the plane generated by $\vec{A}\times\vec{B}$ and $\vec{C}]$,
namely $\vec{A}\times\vec{B}\times\vec{C}$.

The cross product is not associative, so the expression $\vec{A}\times\vec{B}\times\vec{C}$ is meaningless. One plane has normal vector $\vec{A}\times(\vec{B}\times\vec{C})$ and the other has normal vector $(\vec{A}\times\vec{B})\times\vec{C}$, and there is no guarantee these are parallel vectors. In general, the cross product satisfies the Jacobi identity instead of associativity. Also see vector triple product and Vector algebra relations.

Ah! Got it! This was really helpful.

I am doubt whether the angle between two vectors lying in a plane is equal to the angle between the perpendiculars of those vectors in that same plane is true.
Consider two vectors $\vec{A}$ and $\vec{B}$ lying in a plane.
Let $\vec{A'}$ and $\vec{B'}$ be the perpendiculars of $\vec{A}$ and $\vec{B}$ respectively.
Let $\vec{A}=A_x\hat{i}+A_y\hat{j}$ and $\vec{B}=B_x\hat{i}+B_y\hat{j}$.
We can obtain $\vec{A'}$ by rotating $\vec{A}$ 90 degrees, either clockwise or anti-clockwise. Similar for $\vec{B'}$.
Suppose we obtain $\vec{A'}$ by rotating $\vec{A}$ clockwise, but obtain $\vec{B'}$ by rotating $\vec{B}$ anti-clockwise.
Then $\vec{A'}=A_y\hat{i}-A_x\hat{j}$ and $\vec{B'}=-B_y\hat{i}+B_x\hat{j}$.
Let $\theta$ be the angle between $\vec{A}$ and $\vec{B}$. Let $\phi$ be the angle between $\vec{A'}$ and $\vec{B'}$.
Then we have
$$\cos\theta=\frac{\vec{A}\cdot\vec{B}}{|A||B|}$$
and
$$\cos\phi=\frac{\vec{A'}\cdot\vec{B'}}{|A'||B'|}.$$
Notice that $|A'|=|A|$ and $|B'|=|B|$. Also
$$\vec{A}\cdot\vec{B}=A_xB_x+A_yB_y$$
and
$$\vec{A'}\cdot\vec{B'}=-A_yB_y-A_xB_x=-\vec{A}\cdot\vec{B}.$$
So $\cos\phi=-\cos\theta$. Since $-\cos\theta=\cos(\pi-\theta)=\cos(\pi+\theta)$, we have $\phi=\pi-\theta$ or $\phi=\pi+\theta$.
I suspect that $\phi=\theta$ only if both vectors are rotated in the same direction.

Thank you for adding that extra condition and making my understanding better !
